# Dynamic LINQ error in Where clause

Tags: linq

I'm trying to do a `Dynamic LINQ` like in the [ScotGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

```
var select = db.San_Imovel.Where("Imovel_Id = @0", 123).Select("new(Imovel_Id)");
```

but I get the error

> the best overloaded method match for '.Where(string, System.Data.Objects.OBjectsParameter[])' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using .net 3.5?

*Note that only 3.5+ supports that syntax.*

Use `String.Format`:

```
var select = db.San_Imovel.Where(String.Format("Imovel_Id = {0}", 123)).Select("new(Imovel_Id)");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is that 123 for?  In order for this to compile, it will probably need to look like one of these:

```
var select = db.San_Imovel.Where("Imovel_Id = @0").Select("new(Imovel_Id)");
```

OR

```
var select = db.San_Imovel.Where("Imovel_Id = @0 AND SomethingElse = 123").Select("new(Imovel_Id)");
```

Comment: But I need pass the value of Imovel_Id. @0 is like a parameter and then I tell that @0 is 123.